# Connect Informix JDBC over SSL

Tags: spring, ssl, informix, spring-jdbc

I want to connect my Spring JDBC application with SSL. The DBMS is Informix IBM.

I'm using a spring-config.xml file in which I declare the datasource bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.sopra.datasource.CDataSource" init-method="init"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
</bean>
```

Many thanks.

Mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you got a basic SSL connection to the Informix server working, for example using the dbaccess tool? If not you might want to refer to this developerWorks article for the configuration steps:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0912securesockets1/dm-0912securesockets1-pdf.pdf

This article uses Informix 11.50 whereas I was using 12.10 which uses a later version of the IBM GSKit so I substituted the gsk8capicmd_64 command everywhere where the article uses gsk7capicmd.

I have no knowledge of Spring JDBC so I then used a basic JDBC demo program to test the SSL connection. This program was based on the "JDBC sample for SSL connection" program listed in the Informix JDBC Driver Guide:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_490.htm

Here are some relevant extracts from the code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/home/keystore/keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
IfxConnectionPoolDataSource  cds =  new IfxConnectionPoolDataSource();
cds.setIfxIFXHOST("informix_hostname"");
cds.setServerName("informix_server");
cds.setPortNumber(port_number);
cds.setIfxSSLCONNECTION("true");
cds.setUser("informix");
cds.setPassword("password");
cds.setDatabaseName("stores_demo");

conn = cds.getPooledConnection().getConnection();
```

You may also need to configure a Java Cryptography Extension-complian encryption services provider as described in the Encryption Options section of the Informix JDBC Driver Guide:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_059.htm

Comment: Thank you @Simon Riddle for your help, I'm reading the article you've sent me, I'll keep you informed.

Comment: Hi @Simon Riddle! I've made the configuration server part. When I configured the client side I got the following error : org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (com.informix.asf.IfxASFException)

Comment: Is there any additional information available with the exception, such as an error code? I have not used the Apache Commons DBCP component so I don't know if the error code can be obtained. In a regular JDBC connection using the Driver class the getConnection method throws an SQLException for which you can use the getErrorCode and getMessage methods to obtain further information. You should also check the Informix server message log to see if an error appears there.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Simon Riddle! It finally works, I've made IfxConnectionPoolDataSource as a bean in spring context, in combination with SingleConnectionDataSource!